# osacompile changing the AppleScript output so it won't run

Tags: applescript

I have a semi-long AppleScript that I run each morning to launch all of my apps etc. One of the things that it does is launch a few apps and then immediately minimize them. When I paste the .applescript source into Script Editor and run it, everything works fine:

```
-- snip:
tell application "Mail"
    launch
    minimize(window 1) of me
    check for new mail
end tell
-- 'minimize' defined as:
on minimize(w)
    set the miniaturized of w to true
end minimize
```

But when I compile the AppleScript source as follows:

```
osacompile -o ~/Library/Scripts/myscript.scpt myscript.applescript
```

... the compiler munges `minimize` to be:

```
on minimize(w)
    set |miniaturized| of w to true
end minimize
```

And I get this error:

> error "Mail got an error: Can’t make |miniaturized| of window id 30936 into type reference." number -1700 from |miniaturized| of window id 30936 to reference

Anyone have any clue what I'm doing wrong here? For purposes of version control, I need to run the scripts through `osacompile`.

**UPDATE:** To clarify, what seems to be happening is that Script Editor is compiling the method differently than `osacompile` on the command line. Is it known whether they compile different (*e.g.*, using scope inferences or some such thing)?

Comment: Encompassing `miniaturized` in pipes causes the compiler to treat it as a **variable**. Is it inserting the pipes when you compile the code? Also, use `tell application "Mail" to set miniaturized of w to true`

Comment: Right... the source code has `set the miniaturized`... -- it's the only _the compiled output_ that has `|miniaturized|`, which it is doing despite my best efforts to stop it. The reason that I don't want to do `set the miniaturized`... in every tell block for every app is that I'd rather just say `minimize(window 1) of me` in each (w/ the code re-use etc.)

Comment: What are you using to compile the script?

Comment: Using OS X's `osacompile` command in the terminal.

Comment: I think I know why it's inserting pipes. If you take a look at @regulus6633's answer, he says that you have `miniaturized` outside of a tell block and therefore AppleScript thinks that `miniaturized` is a property of AppleScript, which it isn't. As I said in my first comment, use `tell application "Mail" to set miniaturized of w to true`.

Comment: @fireshadow52 - Right. You'll note my comment on his answer though: I understand that this is what's happening, but what I'm trying to understand now is why does it compile different from Script Editor vs. `osacompile`? Provided that the reference passed to the method has a `miniaturized` property (which a Mail window does... which an iCal window does... etc.) then we ought to be able to set that reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code - **I suspect this is a bug in `osacompile`** and I suggest you file a [bug report with Apple](https://bugreport.apple.com) - as I've done.

You can verify that your code works correctly by using `AppleScript Editor` to save it as a `*.scpt` file directly and then running it with `osascript`.
[Updated] By contrast, passing the `*.applescript` source-code file directly to `osascript` does exhibit the problem.

There is no good reason I can think of for `AppleScript Editor`-based compilation to work differently from `osacompile` (and on-demand compilation in `osascript`), and the former's behavior is the expected and desired one in this case.

There are 2 **workarounds**:

- **Enclose the reference to `miniaturized` in a `using terms from application "System Events"` block**:
  This is a generic workaround that should work with windows from any AppleScriptable application.

  ```
  on minimize(w)
      using terms from application "System Events" # WORKAROUND
           set miniaturized of w to true
      end using terms from
  end minimize
  ```
- **Inline the miniaturization command instead of calling a subroutine**:

  ```
  set miniaturized of window 1 to true
  ```

Comment: Oddly, the inline version is the one I'd stumbled across on my own which seemed to work. I do prefer the "`using terms from`" solution though, as that seems to preserve the spirit of it a bit better. Thanks again for your answer -- and I'll be filing my own bug report as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
on minimize(w)
    set the miniaturized of w to true
end minimize
```

This is not correct. You have "miniaturized" outside any application tell block of code, which means that it's an applescript command. It isn't an applescript command though. It's a command of Mail and other applications. It's amazing that it works properly in AppleScript Editor. It really shouldn't. When you have a command that doesn't make sense applescript is good enough to try to make sense of it and sometimes it can overcome your coding mistake. Obviously osacompile can't overcome your coding mistake.

So the way to fix the osacompile issue is to eliminate the coding mistake. You need to have the miniaturized command inside of an application tell block of code.

To see what I mean open the "standard additions" applescript dictionary and try to find the miniaturized command. you won't find it. Now open Mail's applescript dictionary and you will find it. Thus the command belongs to Mail, not applescript.

Comment: It sounds to me like somehow compiling from within the Script Editor app scopes it differently than `osacompile` on its own. I can see that; what seems odd is that I would imagine that Script Editor is using that same `osacompile` under the covers. I wonder how one of them scopes the method to the window object properly and the other does not. Further research seems necessary.

Comment: @regulus6633 There's nothing wrong with the subroutine - it is passed a window reference obtained in the context of the "Mail" application and therefore the property reference should work. If this didn't work, you couldn't ever write generic subroutines that accept *any* - AppleScriptable - application's window objects as parameters - but the fact is you *can*. See my answer.

Comment: If you need to do that then you could just use the statement... using terms from application "Mail"... which would allow it to compile.

Comment: This would make it "Mail"-specific, which defeats the purpose: (a) the OP wanted a subroutine that works with *multiple* applications, (b) there's a potential compiler bug, given that the code is fine and compiles and works OK when created with AppleScript editor, (c) your explanation is wrong: The *generic* `window` class of all AppleScriptable applications is defined in the `Standard Suite` of the **`System Events`** application's dictionary - seems that all app-specific dicts. simply reference that. Thus, the generic workaround is to use `using terms from application "System Events"`.