# How can I select a drop down menu when I save a file using Applescript?

Tags: list, checkbox, click, applescript

I've been trying to program an AppleScript that writes and exports an AppleScript . And so far, I've gotten as far as automating the writing of the script and getting to the "Export..." menu. I've pasted link to a screen shot of the menu that I've gotten to below.

Link to [image](http://postimg.org/image/5tcs3iyb1/full/)

can someone please let me know (in the simplest way possible) a way to automate the clicking of the `Application` option under the drop down menu (is it called that?) named File Format using apple script. Can someone also please inform me of (if there is) a way to automate the clicking of the `Run Only` check box? If you are unsure what is where, the two spots (the list and the check box) is squared in red in the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Darrick Herwehe's answer has the crucial pointer: use `oascompile` to compile AppleScript source code - no need for (cumbersome and error-prone) GUI scripting.

If you wanted to compile your AppleScript (plain-text) source file - e.g., `some.applescript` to:

- application (bundle) `some.app`
- with the execute-only (run-only) option (i.e., the plain-text source code is NOT included in the bundle)

you'd run

```
osacompile -x -o some.app some.applescript
```

Alternatively, you can even provide the source code as a _string:

```
osacompile -x -o some.app -e 'display alert "hello, world"'
```

If you wanted to achieve the same thing from AppleScript itself:

```
set src to "display alert \"hello, world\""
do shell script "osacompile -x -o ~/some.app -e " & quoted form of src
```

Note that the output format - an application bundle in this case - is inferred from the filename extension of the output filename passed to `-o`.

To invoke `some.app` directly from its output folder for a quick test, use:

```
open ./some.app
```

**Caveat**: There's at least 1 bug (around since at least 2012 and still there in OS X 10.9.2) that causes `osacompile` to compile incorrectly; see [osacompile changing the AppleScript output so it won't run](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8835496/45375)

Comment: Would this make the application a "Run Only"?

Comment: @user3541125. Yes. `osacompile`'s `-x` is the equivalent of the `Run-only` checkbox.

Comment: Ok, but the application is going to be sent to other machines, would there be a way to determine the saved Script/Application's path, or is there a way to save it without using a path (i'm assuming that when you save the script into an application using your command, it would require using paths)

Comment: @user3541125: Not exactly sure what you mean. You can specify any output path with `-o`. If you save without a path (with a filename only), as in my example, the output "file" (bundle folder) will be created in the _current_ folder. The source-code file's (compiled) _content_ is fully integrated into the resulting `*.app` bundle, so the relationship between input source file and output bundle doesn't matter.

Comment: So in short, I do not need to put a path?

Comment: @user3541125 Open Terminal. `cd` to the folder where your `*.applescript` source file is located. Run an `osacompile` command analogous to the one in my answer, which will create the `*.app` bundle in the same folder. Test the bundle with `open ./*.app`. If it works, distribute it / move it to `/Applications` or `~/Applications`.

Comment: OK, so I've tried it, however I've been getting an error. What I'm trying to do is make the user specify the name of the script that they want to save using a "set xyz to text returned of (blabla)". Below is a link to a screenshot of the string of code in my application.


Link: http://postimg.org/image/bp76admvb/

I'm obviously doing something wrong. How could I fix this?

Comment: @user3541125: My answer originally assumed that you have existing `*.applescript` files to compile; I've just updated it to hopefully cover your case.

Comment: OK, then to create this applescript, how could I automate the saving of an applescript, using applescript?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Thanks for your time, patience, and help.

Comment: @user3541125: Glad to hear it; you're welcome; For both my benefit and that of future readers: If an answer _solved_ your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark next to it; if you found it at least _helpful_, please up-vote it by clicking the up-arrow icon.